# Do I need to recompile Vim if Python changes a minor version?

Tags: python, vim, shared-library

I use a compiled Vim on my machine.

This compiled vim attempts to load the shared libary libpython3.10.so.1.0

I just updated my system and apparently Python deleted the old Python 3.10 libaries and replaced them with 3.11 libaries. This of course causes my vim to fail because it can no longer find libpython3.10

Is there a way to get this to work or do I have recompile Vim? It seems like a nuisance to have to recompile Vim every time Python upgrades.

I tried creating a symbolic link in /usr/lib from libpython3.10.so.1 to libpython3.11.so.1.0 and after doing that Vim did indeed start normally. Is this the right move, or is it a mistake to do this for some reason?

Comment: Python 3.10 to 3.11 is not a minor upgrade; a minor one would be something like 3.10.6 to 3.10.7. Yes, you need to rebuild it.

Comment: Creating a symlink _might_ work, but there could be hidden landmines if some function calls changed.  This challenge is why people tend to stick to distros; they handle all this mess for you.  I did exactly what you did in the mid 90s, and got tired of it.  Dependency tracking is a pain!

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the bump from Python 3.10 to 3.11 isn’t a minor version change. See [the 3.11 release announcement](https://blog.python.org/2022/10/python-3110-is-now-available.html) for details ([Python 3.10 was released a year earlier](https://blog.python.org/2021/10/python-3100-is-available.html)).

The 3.11 library isn’t backwards-compatible with 3.10, so you need to rebuild Vim. It may *start* with your “compatibility” symlink, but it’s liable to fail when you actually try to use Python features in Vim — and it may fail in non-obvious ways. You won’t need to rebuild Vim for 3.11.*x* upgrades.

If you don’t need Python support in Vim, another option is to build Vim without it; then you won’t need to rebuild Vim for any Python upgrade.